# Is there an R package with which I can model the effects of competition on ideal free distribution?

Tags: r, modeling, r-package

I am a university student working on a research project, because of our local lockdown I cannot go into the field to collect observation data, I am therefore looking for an R package that will allow me to model the effects of competition when testing for ideal free distribution (IFD).

To give you a better idea of what I am looking for I have described the project in more detail below.

In my original dataset (which I received i.e., I did not collect the data myself) I have two patches (A,B) which received random treatments of food input (1:1, 2:1, 5:1). Under the ideal free distribution hypothesis species should distribute into the patches in accordance with the treatment ratios. This is not the case.
Under normal circumstances I would go into the field and observe behaviour of individuals in the patches to see if dominance affects distribution. Since we are in a lockdown I am unable to do so. I am hoping that there is a package out there that would allow me to model this scenario and help me investigate how competition affects IFD.

I have already found two packages called coexist and EcoVirtual but they model coexistence and extinction dynamics, whereas I want to investigate how competition might alter distribution between profitable patches when there is variation in the level of competition.

I am fairly new to R and creating my own package is beyond my skillset at this point, so I would appreciate the help.

I hope this makes sense and thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi LSK! Interesting question! As a side note, it's always good practice to add some copy/paste-able minimal data snippet to your question, using e.g. `dput(myDataExample)`. This may serve as a starting point to work on/with.

Comment: Thanks I'll bear it in mind for the next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, that's an odd place to find another researcher of IFD. I do not believe there are packages on R specifically about IFD. Its too specific and most models are relatively simple to estimate using common tests. For example, the input-matching rule you mentioned can be tested using a simple run-of-the-mill t-test, already included in base R.

What you have is not a coding problem per say, or even an statistical one. It is a biological problem. What ratio would you expect when animals are ideal (full knowledge of the environment), free (no movement costs), but with the presence of competition? Is this ratio equal to the ratio in your dataset? [Sutherland,1983](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4456) suggests animals would undermatch.

I would love to discuss this at depth, given my PhD was in IFD, but I fear you hit the wrong forum.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, and indeed really surprising to find someone qworking on this specifically. My thinking behind this question was inspired by a paper by Křivan et.al. (2008)  reviewing IFD from a game-theory point of view. I was hoping to find something that would allow me to simulate the competition aspect of the model because, as I mentioned I can't go out and observe behaviour. If you have any suggestions about the direction I could take this it would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you have to refine a little bit the concept of "simulating competition". What exactly would be the target? Do you want to generate a prediction on how competition can make animals deviate from IFD?

Comment: Yes :) exactly. From my original data I can see that there is a significant deviation from IFD and I want to play with the idea that this could be due to competition.

Comment: Have you tried fitting Sutherlands' model? It predict that animals would follow a ratio of  R/(N^(1/x))  where x is the deviation caused by competition

Comment: I am looking at this now. Thanks again for your feedback it has been really helpful.

Comment: Hi again, can I just clarify in the equation you send earlier, R = resources in a patch, N = prey/individuals in the patch and x is the deviation from the IFD due to competition?